# Is there any way to prevent Woocommerce from defaulting to one particular (local pickup) shipping method?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, e-commerce

I want to **prevent Woocommerce from defaulting to the local pickup option**.

I do need the local pickup as and option for customers, but not as a default.

I have encountered what I think is a [bug in woocommerce](https://github.com/woothemes/woocommerce/issues/3641) and there is a workaround documented; but the workaround will not work for me because ( apart from hacking the Woocommerce core ) I don't want to default to the most expensive method either, which is how the workaround operates, because I have premium methods.

There is a setting for default method in the Woocommerce settings `woocommerce settings > shipping > shipping methods > radio buttons down the page on the left` ... but it appears to be ignoring this and defaulting to the cheapest method. There is also a ( superfluous setting to pick the cheapest option )

There is already a bug report with Woocommerce; so for now rather than trying to fix that, if I could somehow just override Woocommerce from defaulting to the local pickup option ( or impose my own manual defaults ) then for me that would be a usable workaround.

**EDIT:** this seems to arise if both free shipping and local pickup are enabled - github issue here https://github.com/woothemes/woocommerce/issues/7721

Answer (score 3):

I just dealt with this issue with my client. You can set any shipping service as the default in the shipping options. However, a problem occurs when a new customer has yet to enter a zip code. Without a zip code USPS/UPS/other shipping services can't generate quotes... which leaves local pickup as the only existing option on the cart page.

What we ended up doing for the time being is configuring two options: hiding shipping costs until ZIP is entered and disabling the shipping calculator on the cart page.

For some reason, and I'm not sure why, I also needed this snippet on my live site:

```
// hide shipping on the cart page
add_filter( 'woocommerce_cart_ready_to_calc_shipping', 'so_28974941_hide_cart_shipping' );
function so_28974941_hide_cart_shipping( $show ){
    if( is_cart() ){
        $show = false;
    }
    return $show;
}
```

Comment: Thanks Helga ... I setup a clean install of WordPress with Woocommerce ( In fact I even used wp reset a couple of times ) but even with your settings and code it still persisted to go to local pickup ... my experience is that if local pickup is enabled it will default to local pickup **regardless of any other setting**. Can you think of anything I might be missing ( i'm not in the us I'm not using USPS just flat rate which I thought should not have been affected by ZIP ... but I did try a real US address also ( inc zip) @helgatheviking

Comment: I created a new issue for it ... actually I discovered it seems to only arise if both local pickup and free shipping are active https://github.com/woothemes/woocommerce/issues/7721

Comment: No I can't think of anything else. As I said, my work-around was disabling the shipping calculator on the cart page.

Answer (score -1):

I found this workaround: add one or more zip codes to "Allowed Zip/Post Codes" in the "Local Pickup" settings. With this, the following message appears on checkout shipping: "Please fill in your details to see available shipping methods." When I filled in a Zip that had been saved in "Local Pickup", both shipping methods appeared.

The cool thing is that you can use underscores so 9_____ works for a zip code starting with a 9 (which, incidentally, covers Oregon and California).

`9____,8____,7____,6____,5____,4____,3____,2____,1____,0____` would cover ANY zip code.